# How to set a custom image as the boot logo on UEFI Windows 10 x86?

Tags: windows, boot

Is it possible to change the boot screen logo in Windows 10 that's booting from UEFI? I've found a way for legacy BIOS, but it doesn't work for UEFI.

Comment: [Discussion here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f3af0be8-1853-46eb-a929-cdf6de6463a9/windows-8-custom-boot-logo?forum=w8itproinstall)

Comment: Are you sure your *x86* version of Windows is booting via *UEFI*?

Comment: You know if it is efi boot splash image it will have a black background.

Comment: @DanielB: 100% sure on both points. And my computer doesn't even have legacy BIOS mode, hence the problem.